# Get .pdb file path from windbg

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols, pdb-files

Is there a way to get the path of the pdb file currently used by windbg? Either by a native command, or, preferably, using the plugin API.

So, ideally I want to be able to do something like:

```
printf(getSymbolFile("ntdll.dll"));
```

which would print "c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the windbg command `!lmi mydll.dll`

So for ntdll.dll the image name will display the path:

```
:004> !lmi ntdll
Loaded Module Info: [ntdll] 
         Module: ntdll
   Base Address: 00000000776f0000
     Image Name: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
   Machine Type: 34404 (X64)
     Time Stamp: 51fb164a Fri Aug 02 03:15:38 2013
           Size: 1a9000
       CheckSum: 1a9bda
Characteristics: 2022  perf
Debug Data Dirs: Type  Size     VA  Pointer
             CODEVIEW    22, 101268,  100668 RSDS - GUID: {400F215C-54DA-4047-88F8-4F5C50491495}
               Age: 2, Pdb: ntdll.pdb
                CLSID     4, 101264,  100664 [Data not mapped]
     Image Type: FILE     - Image read successfully from debugger.
                 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    Symbol Type: PDB      - Symbols loaded successfully from symbol server.
                 C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\sym\ntdll.pdb\400F215C54DA404788F84F5C504914952\ntdll.pdb
    Load Report: public symbols , not source indexed 
                 C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\sym\ntdll.pdb\400F215C54DA404788F84F5C504914952\ntdll.pdb
```

This is a bit verbose however.

Thanks to @SeanCline who pointed out the undocumented command `!itoldyouso` which does the same thing as `!chksym`

```
0:030> !itoldyouso ntdll

C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    Timestamp: 51FB164A
  SizeOfImage: 1A9000
          pdb: ntdll.pdb
      pdb sig: 400F215C-54DA-4047-88F8-4F5C50491495
          age: 2

Loaded pdb is C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\sym\ntdll.pdb\400F215C54DA404788F84F5C504914952\ntdll.pdb

ntdll.pdb
      pdb sig: 400F215C-54DA-4047-88F8-4F5C50491495
          age: 2

MATCH: ntdll.pdb and C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

It is still pretty verbose, you save a few lines.

Comment: For only symbol information, you could also use the undocumented command [`!itoldyouso`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2009/09/04/special-command-using-chksym-itoldyouso-to-check-pdb-files-against-modules.aspx).

Comment: @SeanCline ah yes I forgot about that, I will add the output to my answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `lm` (*list modules*) and a module filter (`m`) for `ntdll`:

```
0:017> lm m ntdll
start    end        module name
77aa0000 77c20000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          e:\debug\symbols\wntdll.pdb\370278F5B1BA4A16B0DC8199E9623C3C2\wntdll.pdb
```